# Как изменить элементы списка

Tags: python

Всем доброе утро. Подскажите, как можно эффективнее поменять тип переменных в списке?

Например: есть список: список строго одного порядка: строка - число, строка - число, строка - число....

```
['Шоколад', '50', 'Печенье', '45', 'Яблоко', '20']
```

Нужно превратить числа (цены на продукты) из типа строк в тип int:

```
list_with_menu_and_price = ['Шоколад', '50', 'Печенье', '45', 'Яблоко', '20']

count = 1
int_prices = list(map(lambda x: int(x), list_with_menu_and_price[1::2])) # сделали список с числами цен

del list_with_menu_and_price[1::2] # удаляем строковые цены

for i in int_prices:
    list_with_menu_and_price.insert(count, i) # добавляем по 1 числу в список, вместо ранее удалённых
    count += 2

print(list_with_menu_and_price)
```

**Но есть по эффективнее способ решения этой задачи?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно преобразовать значения прямо "на месте":

```
l = ['Шоколад', '50', 'Печенье', '45', 'Яблоко', '20']    
l[1::2] = map(int, l[1::2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
[el if el.isalpha() else int(el) for el in list_with_menu_and_price]
```